# How to escape error of length when suppressing NA values in data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a lot of NAs but each column has not the different length without the NAs and I would like to have an identical data frame but without the NAs.
So when I am doing :

```
  for (i in 1:length(df[,1]))
      (df[,i]<-df[,i][!is.na(df[,i])])
```

It answers :

```
  Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c(2696L, 2696L, 2640L,  :
```

Do anyone has an idea how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you're attempting in the code in your question because a data.frame is a list structure with a single key restriction: all vectors (or variables) in the list must have the same length. Your code is attempting to create vectors with different lengths, which is not allowed.

You probably just need the `complete.cases` function:

```
complete.cases(df)
```

This removes all rows that have any `NA` value in any column.